# How to call jQuery.AdminLTE in angular cli 1.0.0

Tags: angular, angular-cli, adminlte

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
.....
ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('oke');
    });

    // error
    jQuery.AdminLTE.layout.fix();
}
```

[image: Log screenshot]

How to fix error?

Comment: What is the exact error you got?

Comment: have you declared `declare var jQuery:any` ??

Comment: Provide us your declaration part of the component, please.

Comment: I using import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
and "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40"

Comment: Try posting the full relevant code and you may get some help.  As it stands your question is very low quality and unanswerable.  See [mcve]